# Dynamic max height as a calculation based on the heights of various flexbox items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a list of flex-items. They're divs with some text and a link or two-- they may end up holding some images inside them eventually. These are small descriptions of portfolio items, which I imagine I'll add to as time goes on.

I'd like the total height of my flex container to be calculated as a bit more than half of the totals of all the flex-items. I'd like to manage this with CSS and javascript, but I'm really not sure that's possible.

I know that the standard max-height properties aren't going to do what I want, but I'm not sure there isn't a way to get the CSS flex containers and times to behave with some other property or attribute that I don't understand just yet.

I looked through a number of other posts on dynamic div height-- but didn't manage to understand what I was looking at.

The page in question can be found here:
http://westerneditor.com/index.php/sandbox-2/

### relevant CSS so far:

```
.flex-container {

   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   align-content: top;
   max-height:1100px;
}

.flex-item {

  display: inline-block;
  background: #292920;
  align-self:baseline; 
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;

  padding: 5px;
  width: 190px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  line-height: 21px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

---

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">

<div class="flex-item">
When working for the Writing Center at UVU, I reworked and edited our Chicago/Turabian guide for clarity.
<br>
<a href="http://westerneditor.com/wp-content/uploads/Turabian-Mykle_Law.pdf" rel="">Chicago/Turabian Guide</a>
</div>

<div class="flex-item">
I wrote a guide on writing to your government officials as well.
<br>
<a href="http://westerneditor.com/wp-content/uploads/writingyourgovernmentofficial-Mykle_Law.pdf">Writing Your Government Official</a>
</div>

<div class="flex-item">I also wrote a piece on the Housing First program, designed to reduce homelessness in Utah, particularly in Salt Lake County.
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865605568/Utahs-Housing-First-program-proves-successful-with-large-decrease-in-chronic-homelessness-in-past.html?pg=all" target="_blank">Utah’s Housing First program successful with large decrease in Utah’s chronic homeless</a>
</div>

<div class="flex-item">And a piece that I collaborated on with Drew Clark, about the possible danger glyphosates and their use in the GMO farming industry.
<br>
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865604673/GMOs-not-harmful-to-human-health-but-further-research-into-farming-practices-necessary.html?pg=all" target="_blank">GMOs not harmful to human health, but further research into farming practices necessary</a>
</div>

<div class="flex-item">
While at the Deseret News, I was a major player in soliciting opinion pieces, editing them and arranging them for a couple of larger multi-perspective works.
One of these on the BRT route in Provo, UT.
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865597173/We-must-consider-alternatives-on-Provo7s-BRT-routes.html">We must consider alternatives on Provo’s BRT routes</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865597174/Route-4-is-the-best-option-to-bringing-bus-rapid-transit-to-Provo-Orem-before-funding-fades.html">Route 4 is the best option to bring BRT to Provo before funding fades</a>
</div>

<div class="flex-item">
Another multi-perspective work was on Recapture Canyon, in southern Utah, the BLM, and general frustrations over who should control federal lands and how federal offices should treat locally popular destinations.
<br>
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865603399/The-public-interest-in-public-lands.html" target="_blank">Public interest in public lands</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865603398/The-BLM-hasnt-kept-its-own-rules.html" target="_blank">The BLM hasn’t kept its own rules</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865603401/Preserving-our-shared-public-lands.html" target="_blank">Preserving our shared public lands</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.deseretnews.com/article/865603404/The-deficit-of-trust-between-America-and-our-government.html" target="_blank">The deficit of trust between America and out government</a>
</div>
```

---

Comment: No, you're going to need javascript to calculate the total heights and go from there. Flexbox can't do that natively.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery get your classes/divs/id's height(), width() and do what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var total-height = $(".flex-container").height();
        var total-width = $(".flex-container").width();
;})
```

**Edit**
JavaScript

Height of the entire element, including borders.

```
document.getElementById('.flex-container').offsetHeight
```

Height excluding border and scrollbar, but including padding.

```
document.getElementById('.flex-container').clientHeight
```